# How to get the number results from my database on a determined date

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, distinct

first of all, I'm not good at sql, so be gentle ;)

So I have two tables:

VIEW:

> - id_view
> - date
> - ip
> - id_article

ARTICLE

> - id_article
> - id_user
> - date
> - ... and other stuff...

What I want is to get the number and details of 3 articles that has more views.

The statement that I've tried without success is the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT view.id_article)
, view.id_article
, article.date category_name 
FROM view , article 
WHERE view.id_article=article.id_article 
AND article.date="2013-10-18" 
GROUP BY id_article LIMIT 3
```

But I don't get the result that I really want because it only shows the result for one article on that date. That is, I know that article 1 has 1 view on that day, but I have another articles that got views on that particular day.

I really think that is something simple, but I can figure it out by myself... :/

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Found the answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(view.id_article), view.id_article 
FROM view , article 
WHERE view.id_article = article.id_article 
  AND view.date = "2013-10-18" 
GROUP BY id_article
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Have to clarify...are you looking for all articles having 3 or more views?  Or just 3 articles that have the most views?  This query would actually fail (return error) on any DB but MySQL, your group by isn't entirely right...mysql prefers to quietly return 'incorrect' results before it returns an error

Comment: 3 articles that had more views on a particular day. I know that "group by" is not correct but I don't how to make it good lol

Comment: Oh, so in the example you want the 3 articles that had more views on 2013-10-18 than any other day?

Comment: article 1 got 1 view on day 18, 2 views on day 19. article 2 got 2 views on day 18, 4 views on day 19. If I search for the most seen in day 18, I will get those two since the others did not get any views. The same happens in day 19.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to match the requirements you've given me, it's just going to give you three articles viewed on that day in random order...unless that is your requriement.  Expand your test set to include more than 3 records and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if I'm answering your question right...but here goes.

```
select a.id_article, count(1)
from article a inner join view v on v.id_article=a.id_article 
where v.date="2013-10-18" 
group by a.id_article
order by count(1) desc
limit 3
```

This will give you the id_article of the 3 most viewed articles in the date specified in the where clause.  Hope this is what you wanted...

just post script, view and date are reserved words, best not to use them as column or table names.

Comment: did not work, but I already found the answer. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @Twelfth, there's a kind of typo in your answer, check the from line, you have the table article alias "a" after the inner, fixing that will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
select * from article where article_id in 
(
       select article_id from
       (
            select count(*) as a, article_id
            from view
            where date = '[Pass your date here]'
            group by article_id
            order by a desc
            limit 3
       ) as C
)
```

The downside of this code is you can't preserve the descending order of your article base on number of views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.*, g.count
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(1) as count , id_article
FROM view
WHERE date = "2013-10-18"
GROUP BY id_article ) g
INNER JOIN article a ON a.id_article = g.id_article
ORDER BY g.count DESC LIMIT 3
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df246/1)

Comment: @Th3lmuu90, I think the solution you put in the question doens't work because it's not ordering the results before applying the limit 3